# Overwritting Javascript function variable on demand

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope, dom-events

My problem has to do with being able to overwrite the variables declared within a function but not on every recall on the function. Here is my explanation:

Let's say I have three HTML elements when the page is loaded:

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
```

I then run a javascript function manipulating each of these elements and applying functions to the "onmousemove" event. During the function call there are variable that are declared and should NOT be overwritten in order to keep the variable values unique to the element (otherwise mouse movement would be overwritten and would only work for the last element). I know this can be achieved by declaring them local variables.

My issue is the next part:

After this has all been done, I then have other events on the page that trigger the initial function to run again on the same element it ran on initially, but with different values, which now have to overwrite the originals. I would post the code but it is a few thousand lines of code so I'm hoping you all understand what I'm talking about.

I think I can fix this issue by duplicating the function and declaring the variables differently, but that would mean having two copies of a large block of code, which is never a good idea, in my opinion and I would like to avoid that.

Comment: What you have described should only require less than 10 lines of code. Please copy the relevant sections so we can help you.

Comment: May be try to post a simplification (a simple example) of what you have and what you try to achieve

Comment: yeah, I figured it would be hard to explain/understand. I will try  to write a simplified version and post it. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out how to achieve what I wanted. I reworked my code into Objects. When I run the code initially each element has its own object with a variable global variable (window[element+'obj']) that manipulates the element with prototype methods, which keeps each elements values separate, then when I need to overwrite the values for a particular element, I call a method that resets all the values for that object. I will try to post some example code later for anyone that runs into this issue.

Thanks!